# What are possible methods of updating DIV or ID onclick without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is snenario

```
<div id="menu">
 <div id="menuwrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id="m1" onclick="dates('from','to','2012-12-01','2012-12-31');">Mymenu1</li>
    <li id="m2" onclick="dates('from','to','2011-12-01','2011-12-31');">Mymenu2</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here `onclick` I am calling javascript `dates()` which creates data widget where first 2 arguments `from` and `to` are division id, and argument 3 and 4 are ranges.

But problem is simultaneously both won't work for example if I clicked on `Mymenu1`, it shows `datepicker` with date range from `'2012-12-01','2012-12-31'` and now if I click on `Mymenu2` it again shows same date range showed before here I expect `'2011-12-01','2011-12-31'`.

Is there any way to overcome from this problem ? I am creating menu dynamically in php with the help of this tutorial http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Dynamically-Create-Menu-With-PHP-DOM.html.

Please guys help me, I guess I have to update `from` and `to` id after `dates` function is called but I don't know how to achieve this without reloading complete `index.php`, I Hope my problem is clear.

Have a nice day..

Comment: is the dates() function yours or built in ?

Comment: Its datepicker user defined

Comment: you can create a new function myDates that will be called onClick, and in the myDates function u reset datepicker and then call dates(). to reset datepicker use     `$.datepicker._clearDate(this);`

Comment: you may need to re-initialise your datepicker() on second call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$("selector").datapicker("destroy");`

http://jsfiddle.net/Kq3uj/

Comment: are you using jQuery or $ as variable? what does the console say?

Comment: No message simply blank

Comment: is the variable of your jQuery $ or jQuery? did you try jQuery.datepicker. .?

Comment: I don't know much about it as you have shown in script part I copied the same

Comment: this line is making result blank nothing is coming `$.datepicker._clearDate(this);`

Comment: please try jQuery.datepicker._clearDate(this); if this does not work, please provide some more of your sourcecode, and what variable your jQuery uses

Comment: sorry, but this does not help at all, where is the `dates()` onclick function and all the other code (HTML)?